# Why am I unable to echo the value of php define() function?

Tags: php

I am creating a `define()` function to keep my database host name there:

```
define("hostname","www.dbhost.com");
echo hostName;
```

But it outputs: `hostName`, and not the `dbname`.

The problem is that the function is not returning the second parameter of the `define()` function. Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: By default, defines are case-sensitive. Your example exhibits all lowercase vs camel case.

Comment: Using upper case for constants created by the define function is the convention http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: if you just enabled error reporting including notices you will get `Notice: Use of undefined constant hostName - assumed 'hostName'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hostname` is not the same as `hostName`, unless you declared the constant to be case-insensitive like this:

```
define("hostname","www.dbhost.com", true);
```

In my opinion, it is besser to use case-sensitive names.

Comment: Thanks, it works! so, can I use quotes for true? I mean "true"?

Comment: @patriciaperez I did not try that but I believe that every value which can be evaluated to `true` might be treated as `true`. Why would you want to use quotes?

Answer (score 1):

It's case sensitive, so `hostName` doesn't match your define of `hostname`.

Moreover, when you use an 'undefined define', PHP assumes that you meant a string that contains the name of the define. (*) So that's why you see text `hostName`.

Comment: (*) I think something stronger than alcohol was used when that feature was written.